# changing variable value from within a function

Tags: c

I'm writing a program in c in which I need to change the value of a variable from within a function.

I've tried setting the variable globally but it was not recognized withinn the function

So I tried the following:
the variable is nobuttons:

```
readconfig(config2, &nobuttons);

void readconfig(FILE * config, int * buttons) {
    buttons = 5;
}
```

when I print the value of `buttons`, it's shown as `0`(the value it was initialized to)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Compile with warnings set to their highest level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `*buttons = 5;` instead of `buttons = 5;`

> when I print the value of buttons, it's shown as 0(the value it was initialized to)

The value of `button` is not initialized but as you know, the [global variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) by default initialized with `0` hence you get `0` when you print it.

`buttons=5;` means the address of `buttons` pointer now holding address `5` whereas, `*buttons = 5;` means the content of `buttons` pointer is changed with value `5`. Remember, the content of whom `buttons` pointer points will be updated by `5` now.